# Exercise on limits: is this proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x^\alpha \ln{x}=0$$ for every $\alpha>0$

This is my attempt:

Let

1. $g(x)=x^x$
2. $f(x)=x^\alpha$
3. $h(x)=g\circ f(x)=(x^\alpha)^{(x^\alpha)}$
4. $k(x)=x^{(x^\alpha)}$

Since  $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=0^\alpha=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)=1$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}h(x)=1$ by the theorem of limit of composite function. Moreover, we notice that $h(x)=(x^\alpha)^{(x^\alpha)}=(x^{x^\alpha})^\alpha=k(x)^\alpha$; therefore, $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}k(x)=(\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}h(x))^{(1/\alpha)}=1$.

Finally, we note that $x^\alpha \ln{x}=\ln{x^{(x^\alpha)}}=\ln{k(x)}$. Again by the theorem on limit of a composite function, and by the fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\ln x=\ln 1=0$, we find that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\ln(k(x))=0$$

Are there any mistakes? I don't think it's quite right because I apparently haven't used the hypothesis that $\alpha>0$. Moreover...could it have been written in a better way? For example, I understand that the proof relies on the theorem about the limits of function restrictions, should I have pointed it out? Thanks for any hints.

Comment: You do actually make use of $\alpha > 0$ when you say that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Going in a completely different direction, have you considered using L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: In the textbook I'm studying, the exercise is presented before the chapter on derivatives, so I guess the author wanted me to find an alternative way :)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  Your proof looks good, overall.

Comment: Assuming you have a proof that $\lim_{x\to 0}x^x = 1$ it looks OK. What is your proof of that?

Comment: To prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x^x=1$ was an earlier exercise. I proved it like this: we notice that $x^x$ is the composition of the functions $(1/x)^{1/x}$ and $1/x$; since the former converges to $1$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ (this was an exercise presented still before) and the latter to $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0+$, by the theorem of composite functions, our limit equals 1

Comment: My proof that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x^{1/x}=1$ went like this: let $a_n$ be a sequence converging to $\infty$, and let $b_n=n^{1/n}$, then $c_n=a_n^{1/a_n}=b_n\circ a_n$. Since $b_n$ converges to $1$, $c_n$ does too. By the theorem that relates limits of sequences and of functions (I don't know the name in English, in my language it's 'bridge theorem'), the thesis follows. Then, of course, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1/x)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}1/(x)^{1/x}=1/(\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x^{1/x})=1$